# Randomize treatments in R using RandomizeR

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R. Just trying to learn R using one randomization project i developed in excel. The specification of randomization project is summarized below
Trial with sample size (N) = 200
Compare standard treatment S, a low dose (L), and a high dose (H) of the experimental treatment
We have K = 3 treatment groups
Equally many patients per group= Use Random Allocation Rule(RAR)

```
library("randomizeR")
N <- 200
K <- 2
groups <- c("S","L","H")
par <- rarPar(N,K,groups-groups)
R <- genSeq(par)
getRandList(R)
```

I got the error error message below, when i run the code: in R studio

```
  > getRandList(R)
  Error in .hasSlot(obj, "M") : object 'R' not found
```

can some tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: You set `K = 2`, but you have 3 groups; they should match. And `N` should be divisible by `K`. Then in the call to `rarPar()`, you have `groups-groups` where you should have `groups = groups`.

Comment: @meriops, you corrections are applied. I now get:Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘genSeq’ for signature ‘"function", "missing", "missing"’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to debug without seeing the exact code leading to the error, but the following edit of your code works for me:

```
library(randomizeR)

N <- 300 
K <- 3 
groups <- c("S", "L", "H") 
par <- rarPar(N, K, groups = groups) 
R <- genSeq(par, r = 10) 
getRandList(R)
```

Comment: your answer works. like you said, N must be divisible by K. How do i add a block of 6?

Comment: What do you mean by "block of 6"?

Comment: i mean to have it as Permuted Block Randomization. The block size of 6.

Comment: I think this does the block permuted randomization:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomizeR/versions/2.0.0/topics/rarPar